# How to use DataMapper when data loading aspect needs to be optimized?

Tags: php, database, caching, optimization

I have a DataMapper that creates an object, and loads the object with the same data from DB quite often.  I have the DataMapper in a loop, to where the object that is being created essentially keeps loading the same SQL over and over again.

How can I cache or reuse the data to ease the load on the database?

**Code**

```php
$initData = '...';
$result = '';
foreach($models as $model)
{
    $plot = (new PlotDataMapper())->loadData($model, $initData);
    $plot->compute();
    $result[$i] = $plot->result();
}


class PlotDataMapper
{
     function loadData($model, $initData)
     {
           $plot = Plot($initData);

           //If the loop above executes 100 times, this SQL
           //executes 100 times as well, even if $model is the same every time
           $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM .. WHERE .. $model");
           $plot->setData($data);
           return $plot;      
     }
}
```

**My Thoughts**

My line of thought is that I can use the DataMapper itself as a caching object.  If a particular $model number has already been used, I store results in some table of the `PlotDataMapper` object and retrieve it when I need it.  Does that sound good?  Kind of like *memoizing* data from DB.

Comment: Do you want to cache across requests?

Comment: probably not... that seems more involved and more like a whole-application solution for caching DB requests.  Still could be of interest though as it may help also with other things.  But in this case, for example I know what is being inefficient, and can implement something concrete.